# how to get key by value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some problem to fetching key of matching value in array. Here is my array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1001;vbaker;Test@test.com;Vern;Baker;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1002;Tesdsd;Test@test.com;Test;vbaker;
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1003;demosa;demo@dime.com;Baker;Tesdsd;
        )

)
```

So here for example, I want get **key** of **1002**(value).. How do I get that ..?
My need is ,I have only the id(say 1002) so I have to get the other values like `Tesdsd;Test@test.com;Test;vbaker;`

Comment: Loop through the array and use explode() to separate on the semicolon?

Comment: By "key", do you mean the index of the outer array? So given `1002`, you want the result to be `1`?

Comment: yes..I want get the index of particular matching value

Comment: Your update seems to contradict that.

Comment: Each element in your array is an array of length 1, each solo-child element containing a string. Are you suggesting that you explode that string into an array (delimiter `;`) such that the expected result searching for "1002" would be `[1][0][0]`?

Comment: "I have only the id(say 1002) so I have to get the other values like Tesdsd;Test@test.com;Test;vbaker;" So you are not looking for a key, you're looking for the remaining string from a element that begins with that searchphrase followed by a `;`

Comment: @Popnoodles Any how I want get the remaining values. I thought if I get the key, so then I can easily get the remaining values..

Comment: @Elavarasan but you're finding the string by having to search for a part of it, so why make more work to find the key only to find the string from that key, when you had the string already.

Comment: @Popnoodles So How to achieve by less walk..? Please give me a solution ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array, split on `;`, store the first and last parts into variables (`$first` and `$last`), check if `$first` is the same as your search string, and if so return `$last`:

```
$search = 1002;

foreach ($array as $key => $sub) {
    list($first, $last) = explode(';', $sub[0], 2);
    if ($first == $search) {
        echo $last;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Tesdsd;Test@test.com;Test;vbaker;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/140428)

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I need to get the key..for fetching other values..please have a look at my updated question..

Comment: @Elavarasan: I'm confused after seeing your update. Could you edit your question to include the expected result so that I can understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: The array is a csv file. I just convert it to array. It contains users details, like id, name, email etc..For my purpose I want get all details of that user by id. So I want get details of user_id 1002. How do I achieve that ..?

Comment: @Elavarasan: Personally, I'd use something like `while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) { ... }` and store it in an array and then search the array afterwards. But does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Amal..Finally I got fixed with your answer, but additionally I want get the key for the matching value(1002).. like. $array[0][1][0];

Answer (score 1):

To get the value:

```
$search = 1002;
$result = array_values(preg_grep("/$search/", call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array)))[0];
```

Which gives:

```
1002;Tesdsd;Test@test.com;Test;vbaker;
```

Then you can `explode()` on `;` and get the parts you want.

To get the key/index (which is 1) try:

```
$search = 1002;
$key = key(preg_grep("/$search/", call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I love PHP's array functions so much, here are my 2 cents:

```
$search = '1003';

$matches = array_filter($array, function($v) use ($search) {

    return strpos($v[0], $search) !== false;

});

echo 'The keys are: ' . implode(', ', array_keys($matches));
```

//EDIT:

If you don't actually need the **keys** (as you said in your original question) but also want to work with the **values**, this may be a better approach:

```
$search = '1003';

array_walk($array, function($v, $k) use ($search) {

    if ( strpos($v[0], $search) !== false )
    {
        // do whatever you want with the data
        echo 'Found ' . ltrim($v[0], $search.';') . ' at key ' . $k;
    }

});
```

The other answers will also do the trick, but as I said, I'm a huge fan of array functions, because I find them more elegant than loops.

Comment: @AmalMurali What the... The updated question is completely different from the original one.

Comment: Yes. The updated question reads "*My need is ,I have only the id(say 1002) so I have to get the other values like `Tesdsd;Test@test.com;Test;vbaker`*" — your code will output `2` (which I assume is not what the OP wants).

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks for the clarification, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right tracks...

```
$yourKey = null;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value == $someSearchQuery){
        $yourKey = $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right.. this should get him into the right tracks though.